# Set multiple search filter in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I need help because i'm stuck in my reactjs project. I'm trying to make multiple search input box with different filter each in reactJS, but i can't achieve it with more than one filter. I tried googling it but i cannot make it work.

```
searchFilter = () => {
    return <form>
              <input name="filterTitle" type="text" value={this.state.filterTitle} onChange={this.filterList}/>
              <input name="filterYear" type="text" value={this.state.filterYear} onChange={this.filterList}/>
              <input name="filterReso" type="text" value={this.state.filterReso} onChange={this.filterList}/>
           </form>
}

filterList = (event) => {
    var items = this.state;
    var updatedItems = this.state.items.filter(item => {
        var filterTitle = this.state.filterTitle != "" ? item.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 : true;
        var filterYear = this.state.filterYear != "" ? item.ano.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 : true;
        var filterReso = this.state.filterReso != "" ? item.reso.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 : true;
        return filterTitle && filterYear && filterReso;
    })
    this.setState({ updatedItems: updatedItems });
    console.log(updatedItems);
}
```

UPDATE 1:

new code so far, please help!

```
handleSearchFilter = (event) => {
  const inputValue = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ input: inputValue });
  this.filterList(inputValue);
};

searchFilter = () => {
    return <form>
              <input name="filterTitle" type="text" value={this.filterTitle} onChange={(e)=>this.handleSearchFilter(e)} />
              <input name="filterYear"  type="text" value={this.filterYear} onChange={(e)=>this.handleSearchFilter(e)} />
              <input name="filterReso"  type="text" value={this.filterReso} onChange={(e)=>this.handleSearchFilter(e)} />
           </form>
}

filterList = (inputValue) => {
    const {items, updatedItems} = this.state;
    const itemsUpdate = this.state.items.filter(item => {
        var filterTitle = item.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > 1;
        var filterYear = item.ano.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > 1;
        var filterReso = item.reso.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > 1;
        return filterTitle + filterYear + filterReso;
    })
    this.setState({ updatedItems: itemsUpdate });
    console.log(updatedItems);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to save search key seperate in state then make AND or OR comparison to retrive result like this

```
import React from "react";

class TestPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      {
        titulo: "titulo1",
        ano: "ano1",
        reso: "reso1",
      },
      {
        titulo: "titulo2",
        ano: "ano2",
        reso: "reso2",
      },
    ],
    updatedItems: [],
    filterTitle: "",
    filterYear: "",
    filterReso: "",
  };

  searchFilter = () => {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          name="filterTitle"
          type="text"
          value={this.filterTitle}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleSearchFilter(e, "filterTitle")}
        />
        <input
          name="filterYear"
          type="text"
          value={this.filterYear}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleSearchFilter(e, "filterYear")}
        />
        <input
          name="filterReso"
          type="text"
          value={this.filterReso}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleSearchFilter(e, "filterReso")}
        />
      </form>
    );
  };

  handleSearchFilter = (event, key) => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ [key]: inputValue }, () => {
      this.filterList();
    });
  };

  filterList = () => {
    const itemsUpdate = this.state.items.filter((item) => {
      var filterTitle =
        item.titulo
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(this.state.filterTitle.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      var filterYear =
        item.ano.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filterYear.toLowerCase()) >
        -1;
      var filterReso =
        item.reso.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filterReso.toLowerCase()) >
        -1;
      return filterTitle && filterYear && filterReso;
    });
    this.setState({ updatedItems: itemsUpdate }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.updatedItems);
    });
  };

  renderList = () => {
    const { updatedItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {updatedItems.map((updatedItem) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {updatedItem.titulo}
              {updatedItem.ano}
              {updatedItem.reso}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.searchFilter()}
        {this.renderList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: Same case as above, i keep getting, TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: can you tell me on which line because I am not getting any error?

Comment: @HomerO you can clone and test my boilerplate https://github.com/nomi9995/multiSearchReact.git

Comment: When i use the filters: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
(anonymous function)
  93 | filterList = () => {
  94 |     const {items, updatedItems, filterTitle, filterYear, filterReso} = this.state;
  95 |     const itemsUpdate = this.state.items.filter(item => {
> 96 |         var filterTitle = item.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTitle.toLowerCase()) > 1;

I defined in constructor and didmount functions...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214026/discussion-between-homero-and-muhammad-numan).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to store the input values corresponding to each input in state and post that you need to filter the items array.

I assume you wish to do an AND operation on filters. IF you wish to do an OR operation just change it in the code below

```js
handleSearchFilter = (event) => {
  const {value, name} = event.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value }, () => {
      this.filterList();
  }); // use setState callback to now filter the list

};

searchFilter = () => {
    return <form>
              <input name="filterTitle" type="text" value={this.state.filterTitle} onChange={this.handleSearchFilter} />
              <input name="filterYear"  type="text" value={this.state.filterYear} onChange={(e)=>this.handleSearchFilter} />
              <input name="filterReso"  type="text" value={this.state.filterReso} onChange={this.handleSearchFilter} />
           </form>
}

filterList = () => {
    const {items, updatedItems, filterTitle, filterYear, filterReso} = this.state;
    const itemsUpdate = this.state.items.filter(item => {
        var filterTitleRes = item.titulo.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTitle.toLowerCase()) > 1;
        var filterYearRes = item.ano.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterYear.toLowerCase()) > 1;
        var filterResoRes = item.reso.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterReso.toLowerCase()) > 1;
        return filterTitleRes && filterYearRes && filterResoRes;
        // Change the above condition to or if you wish to do an OR check
    })
    this.setState({ updatedItems: itemsUpdate });
    console.log(itemsUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Tried like that last week but didn't work, i keep getting:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: I am pretty sure that in such a case the issue would have been that not all your items contain `titulo`, `ano` and `reso` fields as strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use [js-search](https://github.com/bvaughn/js-search) for optimized searching across multiple keys in JSON object.
In your case, you can simply create a smaller JSON array where you only store keys in which you want to search for example

```
import * as JsSearch from 'js-search';

var theGreatGatsby = {
  isbn: '9781597226769',
  title: 'The Great Gatsby',
  author: {
    name: 'F. Scott Fitzgerald'
  },
  tags: ['book', 'inspirational']
};
var theDaVinciCode = {
  isbn: '0307474275',
  title: 'The DaVinci Code',
  author: {
    name: 'Dan Brown'
  },
  tags: ['book', 'mystery']
};
var angelsAndDemons = {
  isbn: '074349346X',
  title: 'Angels & Demons',
  author: {
    name: 'Dan Brown',
  },
  tags: ['book', 'mystery']
};

var search = new JsSearch.Search('isbn');
search.addIndex('title');
search.addIndex(['author', 'name']);
search.addIndex('tags')

search.addDocuments([theGreatGatsby, theDaVinciCode, angelsAndDemons]);

search.search('The');    // [theGreatGatsby, theDaVinciCode]
```

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood the question. what i want is three input fields with a different properties filter on each one.

Comment: oh okay, I have checked your edited answer and it is not optimized, wait let me post an optimized and preferred way